# Encrypted cookies for storing session data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning Spring MVC and I'm not able to understand where and how session data is stored.

What I would like to achieve is storing the session data in an encrypted cookie sent to the browser. This is necessary because I plan to run the application on heroku, which does not have sticky sessions. (This is a solution I already use with python, by using pyramid and beaker and I'm pretty happy with it)

I have this toy controller

```
public class HelloController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");

        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        myModel.put("key", "value");

        return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);
    }
}
```

What happens if I call

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

in the handleRequest method? I think a session is started in case it does not exist, otherwise the existing one is returned. But where is this session stored? In the browser with a cookie? Or somewhere else?

How can I specify that the session has to be put in a cookie and set the key that has to be used to encrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not directly tell spring/web app to store session data to cookie.

you will need to do below in order to achieve your requirement

1. create each cookie for each data to be stored and then add cookie to response

   ```
   Cookie c = new Cookie("sessionid", sessionid);
   res.addCookie(c);
   ```
2. and read cookie data from request

   ```
   Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
   ```

in this case you will have full control over encryption also.

to automize this process means sychronizing session data to cookie you will be able to write aspect handlers.

Comment: do you know where spring stores the session?

Comment: i don't think it has some thing to do with spring, it will be HTTPSession only, and will be in memory.